# VBA, Sorting data in worksheets by unqiue strings

Tags: vba, excel

My current macro takes my data row by row from workbook A or worksheet A and splits it into different sheets based on matching headers. I am having trouble taking it a step further and splitting the string fields among these sheets.

For example, my data in workbook A, column B, contains 10 unique strings, how can I sort string x to one sheet only, and strings the rest of them to other sheets. So the row that contains sheet x will go to a certain sheet and strings abc will act as normal.

Here is my code so far, specifically call out the workbook and sheet names so it is not dynamic:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dsRng As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim AShtColsList As String, BShtColsList As String

    Set dsRng = Workbooks("Workbook A").Worksheets("Sample Extract").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| set your entire data set range in workbook "A" worksheet "ShtA" (change "A" and "ShtA" to your actual names)
    dsRng.Sort key1:=dsRng.Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes '<--| sort data set range on its 1st column (which is "A", beginning it from column "A")

    With Workbooks("Workbook B") '<--| refer "B" workbook
        For Each sht In .Worksheets(Array("Stack", "Documentation", "Users")) '<--| loop through its worksheets
            GetCorrespondingColumns dsRng, sht, AShtColsList, BShtColsList '<--| build lists of corresponding columns indexes in both workbooks
            CopyColumns dsRng, sht, AShtColsList, BShtColsList '<--| copy listed columns between workbooks
        Next sht
    End With
End Sub

Sub GetCorrespondingColumns(dsRng As Range, sht As Worksheet, AShtColsList As String, BShtColsList As String)
    Dim f As Range, c As Range
    Dim iElem As Long

    AShtColsList = "" '<--| initialize workbook "A" columns indexes list
    BShtColsList = "" '<--| initialize workbook "B" current sheet columns indexes list
    For Each c In sht.Rows(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through workbook "B" current sheet headers in row 2     *******
        Set f = dsRng.Rows(1).Find(what:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) '<--| look up data set headers row for workbook "B" current sheet current column header
        If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if it's been found ...
            BShtColsList = BShtColsList & c.Column & "," '<--| ...update workbook "B" current sheet columns list with current header column index
            AShtColsList = AShtColsList & f.Column & "," '<--| ...update workbook "A" columns list with corresponding found header column index
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Sub CopyColumns(dsRng As Range, sht As Worksheet, AShtColsList As String, BShtColsList As String)
    Dim iElem As Long
    Dim AShtColsArr As Variant, BShtColsArr As Variant

    If AShtColsList <> "" Then '<--| if any workbook "B" current sheet header has been found in workbook "A" data set headers
        BShtColsArr = Split(Left(BShtColsList, Len(BShtColsList) - 1), ",") '<--| build an array out of workbook "B" current sheet columns indexes list
        AShtColsArr = Split(Left(AShtColsList, Len(AShtColsList) - 1), ",") '<--| build an array out of workbook "A" corresponding columns indexes list
        For iElem = 0 To UBound(AShtColsArr) '<--| loop through workbook "A" columns indexes array (you could have used workbook "A" corresponding columns indexes list as well)
            Intersect(dsRng, dsRng.Columns(CLng(AShtColsArr(iElem)))).Copy sht.Cells(2, CLng(BShtColsArr(iElem))) '<--| copy data set current column into workbook "B" current sheet corresponding column starting from row 2     *******
        Next iElem
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Complete extract. Call this Sample extract in workbook B.
[image]

'Users' Sheet. My Macro already does this.

[image: enter image dhereescription]

'Documentation' Sheet, my macro already does this too

[image]

'Stack' Sheet. my macro does not do this. It filtered the record stackoverflow and its pertaining columns.

[image]

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @Ralph, ill post some sample screenshots in a few.

Comment: Updated with pictures now, hopefully this may make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

get your data saved in sheet named "data". and below code will generate separate sheets for every unique value in column B with data of corresponding value.

```
Dim data, sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim counter As Long

Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")
data.Activate
Range("B:B").Copy
Range("H:H").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("H:H").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
Set rng = data.Range("H2")

Do While rng.Value <> ""
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
sht.Name = rng.Value
data.Activate
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=rng.Value
Range("A1:C1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy
sht.Activate
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("A1").Activate
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

It will create sheets in same workbook.